# DA structure of a Dehn twist

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology, sg.symplectic-geometry

I am trying to find the DA bordered homology structure of a Dehn twist.In  https://arxiv.org/pdf/0810.0687v6.pdf page 255 bottom the authors tabulate the differentials of the right module(A side) of the DA structure. I am interested in the differentials of the left module the(D side). For the left module(the D side ) they comment it is just algebra tensor generators and dont comment on the differential. Does that mean the differential is zero or else what is it or where to
find it.